# OpenAPI 3 python-flask: how to use multiple content types in response

Tags: python-3.x, flask, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

In the OA3 documentation it states that you can have multiple response content types like this:

```
paths:
  /users:
    get:
      summary: Get all users
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A list of users
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ArrayOfUsers'
            application/xml:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ArrayOfUsers'
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
```

How do I specify that I want to return a specific content type in the controller of a generated python-flask app?

Here's the response portion of the spec that I am trying to implement:

```
      responses:
        "200":
          description: successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/CoordinateResponse"
            text/csv:
              schema:
                type: string
```

I've got a string variable called `response_value` in my controller with the contents of a CSV file.

I tried a bunch of different things, such as

```
return response_value, 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/csv; charset=utf-8'}
```

> produces a response with `Content-Type: application/json`

and

```
from connexion.lifecycle import ConnexionResponse
return ConnexionResponse(body=response_value, status_code=200, content_type='text/csv')
```

> produces no response

and

```
from flask import Response
return Response(response_value, mimetype='text/csv')
```

> produces no response

and

```
from flask import make_response
output = make_response(response_value)
output.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
return output
```

> produces no response

How do I get it to respond with `Content-Type: text/csv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working like this:

```
            from io import BytesIO
            mem = BytesIO()
            mem.write(response_value.encode('utf-8'))
            mem.seek(0)

            from flask import send_file
            return send_file(
                mem,
                as_attachment=True,
                attachment_filename="somefile.csv",
                mimetype='text/csv'
            )
```

As soon as I post a stackoverflow question I stumble on the answer. Story of my life.

Comment: what is `response_value` here? I am having the problem with returning XML via get request :(

Comment: @Zafar `response_value` is just my CSV data. I'm guessing you can do the same thing for XML using `mimetype='text/xml'` or `mimetype='application/xml'`